# Special arrangements of subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats

I need to arrange my pictures on the way shown in the attached figure. Please any help from you.

[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise, please. It is unclear if you also need the labels on the top and on the left.

Comment: Hi Stefan Pinnow, In fact I have 9 pictures arranged in a 3 columns and 3 rows. Each column contains the evolution in time of the simulation picture on focus. for exemple column 1, we have the evolution of N agents from time t=0 to time t=200. The same as for the other columns. So, I want it exactly like I clarified it on the picture.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Yes I need the labels both on the top and on the left. But the top  labels are for columns and the left labels are for rows. There is no label for each picture. I need a one caption for the entire arrangement.

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but surely not of the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved for example with the `tikz` package and the `matrix` library. Here is a dummy picture showing a similar thing as in your question with the corresponding result.

```
% works with tikz v3.0.1a
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        matrix,
    }
    % define size of rectangular pictures
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Size}{25mm}
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        Pic/.style={
            minimum size=\Size,
            inner sep=0pt,
            % this is just to show something
            % comment the two following lines or adjust them accordingly
            draw=black!50,
            fill=black!25,
        },
    ]
        \matrix [
            % typeset nodes in math mode
            matrix of math nodes,
            % use a smaller font for the nodes
            node font=\scriptsize,
            % rotate all nodes in the first column
            column 1/.append style={
                every node/.append style={
                    rotate=90,
                },
            },
            % set the separations of the columns and rows
            row sep=2.5mm,
            column sep=2.5mm,
        ] {
                    &[-2ex] N = 150 & N = 200 & N = 250 \\[-2ex]
            t = 0   & \node [Pic] {};
                        & \node [Pic] {};
                            & \node [Pic] {}; \\
            t = 100 & \node [Pic] {};
                        & \node [Pic] {};
                            & \node [Pic] {}; \\
            t = 200 & \node [Pic] {};
                        & \node [Pic] {};
                            & \node [Pic] {}; \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \caption{Just a dummy caption}
%        \label{fig:dummy}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Now you simply have to replace the `\node [Pic] {};`s with `node [Pic] {\includegraphics[width=\Size]{<pic name>}};` where `<pic name>` is the corresponding picture name which can be found by the `graphicx` package. Hopefully my comments in the code are sufficient that you can modify sizes and distances on your own.

Please note that the `standalone` documentclass does not provide a `figure` environment, why I have commented these lines of code.

Comment: thanks very much for your helps, the both solutions have been successfully given me what I am willing to do. This gained me much time.

Comment: @khaldi, you are welcome. Two more small comments: I would also add a unit to time, so that it is clear if 200 is in seconds, minutes or years. If you don't know the `siunitx` package yet, give it a try and state it, e.g. as `\SI{200}{\second}`. Please accept one of the solutions as an answer, so it is clear that a solution is given that fits your needs.  Should there be any new solution in the future that will be better than the already chosen one you are free to change the accepted answer at any time.

Comment: Oh Stefan, that is also a great improvement. thanks for your interest. I am so sorry for replying late to your comment.

Comment: @khaldi, not a problem; better late than never ;)

Comment: Hi Stefan, I would ask you about how to precise both width and height and not the size in the line \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Size}{25mm}. because I noticed that this gives me a square container in witch the pictures will be included.

Comment: @khaldi, I assumed you have/need quadratic pictures, because they are displayed in your privided picture. If you want to define the width and/or height use the keys `minimum width` and `minimum height` instead (see [pgfmanual v3.0.1a section 17.2.3 on page 219f](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=219)).

Answer (score 5):

See, if this is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}}}
    &   $N=150$ &   $N=150$ &   $N=250$                             \\
\rotatebox{90}{\qquad$t=0$}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}   \\
\rotatebox{90}{\qquad$t=100$}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}   \\
\rotatebox{90}{\qquad$t=200$}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for your reply, this saved my time. thanks in advance. Both solutions  have been tested and the both have given me what I am seeking to reach.